# Associate a button with a passenger C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

Hi I produced a windows form. The goal is to book seats on a airplane but now i'm finding quite distressing the path that I choose - when the passenger chooses the seat graphically by pressing a button the button's color is being changed but now I need to add a piece of code that could help me save this information and associate it with the passenger. 
Regards

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.F16.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    this.F16.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question is a bit difficult to understand. Could you try rephrasing?

Comment: Your question isn't understandable!!! I don't see the connection between code you pasted and your text above it. Re-done your text question for us to "get it" and if know how than to help you.:-) Got it?;-)

Comment: Do I understand properly that you just need to store somehow the information about seat the passenger selected with the passenger himself?

Comment: As others have indicated... I don't even see an indication that you have a data persistence layer at all.  Are you already saving other information about the passenger?  Do you have a passenger class?  Do you have a database?  Have you literally just designed a form and made the color of something change when you click a button?  If that's all the work you've done then you have a very long way to go.  Way more code / example / information is needed.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English... I need to use serialization to save information. But the answer I received is of good help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, then just create a new class Passenger, where you keep all information about passenger and choosen places by him

```
public class Passenger
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string place { get; set; } // or list of places

    public Passenger(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void savePlace(string newPlace)
    {
        this.place = newPlace;
    }

}
```

Then in your form create a variable

```
private Passenger currentPassenger;
```

And inside of your function save a choosen place

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.currentPassenge.SavePlace(this.F16.name)//or just "F16"
    this.F16.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    this.F16.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

if your have own button for every place, then better assign a place's data in .Tag property

```
this.button4.Tag = "F16"
```

if so then you need only one handler for all buttons

```
    private void PlaceButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        this.currentPassenger.savePlace((string)btn.Tag);
        this.F16.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        this.F16.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

and ofcourse in constructor of Form add event handler to all place's buttons

```
this.button1.Click +=new EventHandler(PlaceButtons_Click);
this.button2.Click +=new EventHandler(PlaceButtons_Click);
this.button4.Click +=new EventHandler(PlaceButtons_Click);
```

Or if you want associate in other way places with passenger then create Place class

```
public class Place
{
    public string Code{ get; set; }//code of place "F16"
    public string passenger { get; set; } //Name of passenger

    public Place(String passengerName)
    {
        this.passenger = passengerName;
    }

    public void SavePassenger(string newpassenger)
    {
        this.passenger = newpassenger;
    }

}
```

And do the same things in event handler PlaceButtons_Click, but save passenger name in Place class. In form create a list of places or hashtable (Place; Passenger) or something else independing on using of application.